# Do braces { } protect me from sql injection with a dynamic query in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-injection

Read this:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

On the dynamic sql part it has various such as this:

```
So, if you had an existing Dynamic query being generated in your code that was going to Oracle that looked like this:
 String query = "SELECT user_id FROM user_data WHERE user_name = '" + req.getParameter("userID") 
 + "' and user_password = '" + req.getParameter("pwd") +"'";
 try {
     Statement statement = connection.createStatement( … );
     ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery( query );
 }
You would rewrite the first line to look like this:
Codec ORACLE_CODEC = new OracleCodec();
 String query = "SELECT user_id FROM user_data WHERE user_name = '" + 
   ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( ORACLE_CODEC, req.getParameter("userID")) + "' and user_password = '"
   + ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( ORACLE_CODEC, req.getParameter("pwd")) +"'";
And it would now be safe from SQL injection, regardless of the input supplied.
```

But the later is says:

```
Oracle 10g escaping

An alternative for Oracle 10g and later is to place { and } around the string to escape the entire string. However, you have to be careful that there isn't a } character already in the string. You must search for these and if there is one, then you must replace it with }}. Otherwise that character will end the escaping early, and may introduce a vulnerability.
```

I did not see an example, but does this mean I can use braces instead of the `Codec ORACLE_CODEC`....etc.?  Does anyone have an example?  Thanks.

Comment: **NO**. The are not a replacement. Supposedly the `ecodeForSQL` protecting this code. As stated **you have to be careful that there isn't a } character already in the string**: that is, imagine the input is "BobbyTables}; DROP this_sucks". Removing it would remove all protections. Just use placeholders ..

Comment: @pst  I do not understand what you mean placeholders.  What do they by the braces?

Comment: Placeholders/prepared statements allows separation of an SQL statements *shape* (`DELETE FROM x WHERE id = ?`) and *data* (id here). In doing so they also eliminate SQL injection attacks on *data* because the *data cannot affect the shape* when using placeholders .. see http://bobby-tables.com/ (The exact method used will depend upon bindings used.)

Comment: If the raw SQL command *must* be sent/used, then **the correct encoding of data *must* be used** to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. It cannot be omitted. It doesn't matter if string literal termination character is `'` or `}`: the exact same SQL vulnerability remains. The use of `{}` is to *make it easier for humans* to enter different strings. {'Hello!' shouted Mary. 'How are you today?'}

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not an injection prevention technique.  The only way to be 100% sure that you're not vulnerable to injection is to use prepared statements and bind parameters for all user input that needs to be inserted into the query.  Anything less than that, and you're pretty much just rolling the dice.

Comment: Well, prepared statements are [almost always] the *best* way (+1) where they are permissible, however, if *correct* escaping is always done (which might vary based on database connection settings and other obscure nuances) then it is equal as "secure". I am not vouching for anything *other* than prepared statements (as my comments above should indicate ;-), but "rolling the dice" seems misleading.

Comment: @pst Prepared statements are *easy*.  Properly escaping is *hard* & even doing a half-assed job is more work than a prepared statement.  I can't understand why people continue trying to do it.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething I don't understand why placeholders aren't used everywhere either. But it's not always an option (this may or may not indicate another design issue, but ..). Even in cases where it is not an option there are still secure ways of generating "raw" SQL commands within a defined context: Rule #1 (or #1b if #1a is taken as "use placeholders") is guard *everything* correctly (back to the `'` vs `}` question) ..

Comment: @pst: It's nearly impossible to do _correct_ escaping such that your final SQL query is 100% impervious to injection and, most importantly, will _remain that way indefinitely into the future_.  In contrast, this is exactly what prepared statements offer you out of the box.

Comment: A prepared statement does not guarantee that no sql injection will happen. What you probably mean is that if you use prepared statements in combination with bind variables for all the external input sql injection can be avoided

Comment: @steve: That much is obviously implied.  But since I'd hate for a novice to read this and think that preparing the query somehow magically prevents SQL injection by itself, I've edited my answer.